# Run a backup script at systemd shutdown (e.g. copy logs to S3 before instance termination by auto scaling)

Tags: backup, logging, systemd, shutdown

I am trying to send log files to S3 before instance termination. I created .service file in `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/upload-backup.service`, which is this.

```
Description=Testing
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
Requires=network-online.target network.target
DefaultDependencies=no
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/upload_log_to_s3.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: `upload_log_to_s3` being the script present in home and copies the file. This is working independently, so has no issues.

I have also created a soft link for this file in `/etc/systemd/system/shutdown.target.wants/` and also enabled systemctl.

But the script is not running while shutdown or reboot. Please explain the mistake and where I am wrong.

Comment: Just to note, that the directory `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` (see `man systemd-shutdown`) should contain **executables** (not service unit definitions) that will be run _very_ late in the shutdown process – too late for anything that requires network connectivity like uploading to S3.

Answer (score 4):

The trick that worked for me was to use a service unit’s `ExecStop=` to run the script, but the service unit is otherwise “normal”, i.e. `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.

In order to make sure that networking is still available when the command is executed, I added `After=network.target`.

Since I care about the log files generated by a particular service of interest, I added `Before=interesting.service` – in order to make sure that the command is run only after the interesting service had been stopped.

Note that when stopping units, systemd applies the order dependencies of `Before=` and `After=` in reverse, so the above is as intended.

For good measure, I also set the `User=` and `Group=` so that the script does not run as root.

```
[Unit]
Before=interesting.service
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/upload_log_to_s3.sh
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Place the file at `/etc/systemd/system/upload-backup.service`; enable and start it with `sudo systemctl enable upload-backup.service --now`.

Once enabled, the service will be started automatically at boot. Once started, it will sit there doing nothing until shutdown, and on shutdown it will run the script.